# C# WPF - Background color out of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background, border

I'm new in WPF and I try to make a DataGrid with auto generated columns.
Now I got stylized the DataGrid as I want, but there is a problem when the DG is smaller than the ParentContent, and it looks like this.

[image]

I don't like how it is look's that white bar on the right side of the DG but I don't know how to change it's colour. I wish that it look's like in the DataGridView.

[image]

My question is, How can I change the color of that part of the Grid?

**GRID CODE**

```
<DataGrid x:Class="Project.WPF.Grid"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.WPF"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="200"
      Name="dgv_grid"
      Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
      AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
      SelectionMode="Single"
      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
      DataContext="{Binding}"
      Background="#ABABAB" 
      SelectionUnit="FullRow"
      CanUserAddRows="False"
      CanUserReorderColumns="False"
      CanUserResizeColumns="True"
      CanUserResizeRows="False"
      IsReadOnly="True"
      GridLinesVisibility="None"
      HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#A0A0A0"
      VerticalGridLinesBrush="#A0A0A0"
      BorderThickness="1"
      BorderBrush="#636363"
      EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
      RowHeaderWidth="0"
      ColumnWidth="Auto"
      Loaded="dgv_grid_Loaded" 
      AutoGeneratedColumns="dgv_grid_AutoGeneratedColumns"
      AutoGeneratingColumn="dgv_grid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
      MouseDoubleClick="dgv_grid_MouseDoubleClick"
      SelectedCellsChanged="dgv_grid_SelectedCellsChanged">

<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <!--#region Triggers-->
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A0A0A0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A0A0A0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFB6B6B6"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <!--#endregion-->
        <!--#region Setters-->
        <!--<Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>-->
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Myanmar Text"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffffff"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,5,5,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#e5e5e5"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
        <!--#endregion-->
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A0A0A0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A0A0A0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFB6B6B6"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffffff"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#e5e5e5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="33"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>

<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF7B7E99"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF4DA2D8"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ABABAB"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#a0a0a0" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0"/>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,2,6,2"/>
                        <ContentControl FontFamily="Myanmar Text" FontSize="20"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read MSDN's ControlTemplate for DataGrid:

[DataGrid Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates)

You will see a large amount of Codes. 
I don't know if you are familiar with ControlTemplates or not. but there is a ColumnDefinition on ScrollViewer Behind this Codes : 
(In the MSDN I mean)

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false" Background="Black">
     <ScrollViewer.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                 <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
```

You can see that this definition will fill the parent container. because the Middle Column's width is `*` and it will fills whole parent.

I don't know how you can get rid of this column in WPF defaults. but if you have time to style your DataGrid. you can change MSDN's ControlTemplate and Remove this Line :

```
 <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
```

so you will get what DataGridView gives to you.

Comment: I truly dont understand plany of the code is wrote in the link, but how removing the line `columndefinition` is going to have impact in my application, cuz if i understand well you say that i must update the source code of WPF DataGrid Template.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `DataGrid` to stretch horizontally, you could set its `HorizontalAlignment` property to `Left`:

```
<DataGrid x:Class="Project.WPF.Grid" ... HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

If you want to change the background of the empty part, you could put the `DataGrid` in a `Grid` and set the `Background` property of this one:´

```
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <DataGrid ... HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried the first but it does not achieve the effect that the DGV has. About the second one, it may be a good solution but this is an Hosted control into a Winforms application and i have plany lines wrote in a class like `public class CustomGrid : DataGrid` rewrote all the code is not what i want now so i dont thins that nest the control in a Grid is the solution now :(